# Tomcat jvm options

Tags: tomcat, jvm

Hi 
I read somewhere that running a JVM of any server with -server option will improve the performace by at least 20-30 %

I have a tomcat but I have figured out that it is not started with -server option. Is it ok to start tomcat with -server option?

Thanks,
Manoj

Answer (score 2):

What version of the JVM are you using? Modern JVMs (1.5 and above) will auto detect the class of   machine and run in the right mode suitable for the machine.

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html . It should be OK to specify -server explicitly if your machine has >=2GB RAM and 2 or more CPUs.